# Installing APK file to Android Studio-emulator

Tags: sdk, apk, emulation, filepath

I am trying to install an APK file to Android Studio-emulator. I tried adding my SDK/platform-tools directory to CMD. I got 'The system cannot find the path specified', but the file is a zip in my downloads file.

Can you please suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7):

As Google pointed me up to this SO question, I think this answer can yet be useful for someone: just start the emulator, drag and drop your .apk file in the emulator virtual screen.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Studio User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#runningapp)

> You can also drag one or more APKs onto the emulator to install them, and then run them.